# When writting git commit message, how can I use kate instead of vim?

Tags: kde, git, kate

Whenever I use git to commit, or rebase, I am thrown into vim to edit my message, and I would prefer using kate, https://kate-editor.org

Answer (score 2):

First you need to have kate installed.

`sudo apt install kate`

Then you need to set the GIT_EDITOR env var. Likely in your `~/.profile` or equivalent.

```
export GIT_EDITOR="kate --startanon --block"
```

`--block` or `-b`, wasn't necessary until the most recent Ubuntu upgrade (23.10). But it is required to block the terminal and not launch in the background. Otherwise, git would terminate ignoring your changes made in the editor.